# `NIL is not of the expected type REAL in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Experimenting with a simple Bayesian Probabilistic Inference network from example code in a book I'm reading, there seems to be a problem involving updating probabilities for a node. There is no problem updating the node `POPULARITY` but once it tries to update `ELEGANCE`for some reason the error in question occurs. I've tried entering the debugger in allegro, to which it shoes `nil nil` as being the CAR of `prior-prob` and `current-prob` of the arc it's trying to update. I don't understand why, though, because this wasn't an issue with the first node. Here is the code:

```
;;Network representation

(defun odds (prob)
  (/ prob (- 1.0 prob)))

(defun prob (odds)
  (/ odds (1+ odds)))

(defmacro define-node (name prior-prob current-prob arcs)
  `(progn
     (setf (get ',name 'prior-prob) ,prior-prob)
     (setf (get ',name 'prior-odds) (odds ,prior-prob))
     (setf (get ',name 'current-prob) ,current-prob)
     (setf (get ',name 'current-odds) (odds ,current-prob))
     (setf (get ',name 'arcs) ',arcs)))

(defun current-prob (n) (get n 'current-prob))
(defun prior-prob (n) (get n 'prior-prob))
(defun current-odds (n) (get n 'current-odds))
(defun prior-odds (n) (get n 'prior-odds))
(defun sufficiency (arc) (cadr arc))
(defun necessity (arc) (car (cddr arc)))

;Primary evidential variables

(define-node decor 0.5 0.9 ())
(define-node table-setting 0.5 0.8 ())
(define-node surface-cleanliness 0.8 0.8 ())
(define-node air 0.6 0.6 ())
(define-node sounds 0.5 0.5 ())
(define-node clientele 0.5 0.9 ())
(define-node menu 0.5 0.5 ())
(define-node prices 0.5 0.9 ())
(define-node services 0.3 0.9 ())

;Lumped evidential variables

(define-node popularity 0.5 0.6 (indep
                                 (arc sounds 1.5 1.0)
                                 (arc clientele 1.0 0.24)))
(define-node elegance 0.5 0.5   (indep
                                 (arc decor 3.0 0.5)
                                 (arc table-setting 1.0 0.74)
                                 (arc sounds 1.5 0.74)
                                 (arc clientele 1.0 0.5)
                                 (arc menu 1.24 0.74)
                                 (arc prices 1.24 0.74)
                                 (arc service 1.0 0.5)))
(define-node artistry 0.5 0.9   (indep
                                 (arc decor 1.0 0.5)
                                 (arc table-setting 1.0 0.5)
                                 (arc menu 1.5 0.74)
                                 (arc service 1.0 0.5)))
(define-node cleanliness 0.7 0.7 (indep
                                  (arc surface-cleanliness 1.5 0.2)
                                  (arc air 1.5 0.5)))

(define-node taste 0.6 0.6 (indep 
                            (arc popularity 1.5 0.7)
                            (arc elegance 1.5 0.8)))
(define-node texture 0.6 0.6 (indep
                              (arc popularity 1.5 0.7)
                              (arc elegance 1.5 0.8)))
(define-node appearance 0.5 0.5 (indep
                                 (arc artistry 3.0 0.4)))
(define-node quantity 0.5 0.5 (indep
                               (arc popularity 1.5 0.5)))
(define-node correctness 0.5 0.5 (indep
                                  (arc elegance 1.0 0.7)))
(define-node nutrition 0.6 0.6 (indep 
                                (arc popularity 1.1 0.7)
                                (arc elegance 1.8 0.8)))
(define-node hygiene 0.8 0.8 (indep 
                              (arc cleanliness 1.0 0.1)))

(define-node overall-food-quality 0.5 0.5
  (indep
   (and 
    (arc taste 3.0 0.3)
    (arc texture 1.0 0.5))
   (and
    (arc appearence 1.0 0.3)
    (arc correctness 1.3 0.8))
   (arc quantity 1.2 0.8)
   (arc nutrition 1.0 0.3)
   (arc hygiene 1.5 0.2)))

;Update-prob computes P(H|E') for a single arc 
(defun update-prob (h arc)
  (cond 
   ((> (current-prob (car arc))
       (prior-prob (car arc)))
    (report-progress 'supportive h arc)
    (+ (prior-prob h)
       (* (/ (- (prob (* (sufficiency arc)
                         (prior-odds h)))
                (prior-prob h))
             (- 1.0 (prior-prob (car arc))))
          (- (current-prob (car arc))
             (prior-prob (car arc))))))
   (t (report-progress 'inhibitive h arc)
      (+ (prob (* (necessity arc) (prior-odds h)))
         (* (/ (- (prior-prob h)
                  (prob (* (necessity arc)
                           (prior-odds h))))
               (prior-prob (car arc)))
            (current-prob (car arc)))))))

;Report-porgres describes the progress of the updating
(defun report-progress (supp-inhib h arc)
  (cond
   ((null reporting) nil)
   (t
    (format t "~%~a probability updating for node ~a" supp-inhib h)
    (format t " along arc:~%~s with prior odds ~s." arc (prior-odds h))
    (format t "~%Prior and current probabilities of E are ~s and ~s."
      (prior-prob (car arc)) (current-prob (car arc))))))

(proclaim '(special *node*))

(defun effective-arc-lambda (arc)
  (/ (odds (update-prob *node* arc))
     (prior-odds *node*)))

(defun combine-indep-lambdas (arc-exp)
  (apply #'*
         (mapcar #'eval-arc-exp
           (cdr arc-exp))))

(defun combine-conjunctive-lambdas (arc-exp)
  (apply #'min
         (mapcar #'eval-arc-exp
           (cdr arc-exp))))

(defun combine-disjunctive-lambdas (arc-exp)
  (apply #'max
         (mapcar #'eval-arc-exp
           (cdr arc-exp))))

(defun update-nodes (nodes)
  (cond ((null nodes) nil)
        (t (update-node (car nodes))
           (update-nodes (cdr nodes)))))

;;Evaluates arc expression, finding odds updating factor
(defun eval-arc-exp (arc-exp)
  (cond ((eq (car arc-exp) 'arc)
         (effective-arc-lambda (cdr arc-exp)))
        ((eq (car arc-exp) 'indep)
         (combine-indep-lambdas arc-exp))
        ((eq (car arc-exp) 'and)
         (combine-conjunctive-lambdas arc-exp))
        ((eq (car arc-exp) 'or)
         (combine-disjunctive-lambdas arc-exp))
        (t (print '(illegal arc expression)) (print arc-exp))))

;;Update nde computes the new probability for a given node
(defun update-node (h)
  (setq *node* h)
  (setf (get h 'current-odds)
    (* (prior-odds h)
       (eval-arc-exp (get h 'arcs))))
  (setf (get h 'current-prob) (prob (current-odds h)))
  (format t "~%Current probability of a node ~a is ~s.~%" h (current-prob h)))

(defun test ()
  (update-nodes '(popularity elegance artistry cleanliness
                             taste texture appearance quantity
                             correctness nutrition hygiene
                             overall-food-quality)))
(defmacro sp (name current-prob)
  '(progn
     (setf (get (car l) 'current-prob) (cadr l))
     (setf (get (car l) 'current-odds) (odds (cadr l)))))
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: The complete source for the book 'Elements of Artificial Intelligence': http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis479/tanimoto.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of your problems is that the are at least two inconsistencies in the name of the nodes of the graph:

1. Sometime you use `service`, other times `services`.
2. Sometime you use `appearance`, other times `appearence`

(I stopped looking after this two names).

Consider to write a function that checks the consistency of the graph, if you need to change often this program. Also note that there is an error in the definition of the macro `sp` (which is not used). The quote (') should probably be a backquote (`) (this is a typical error when doing copy-paste from other material).

Finally, consider strongly to learn to use the debugger if you want to continue to program in Common Lisp, since it is almost immediate to find the cause of your error with an appropriate use of the debugger.

Comment: It just goes to show I'm a horrible copy and paste jockey, doesn't it ;) For the record though, this book is from '92 and didn't come with the floppy disk. Not to mention I enjoy typing in code by hand so I can experiment with the programs. But yes, DEFINITELY want to use the debugger more often. Thank you! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

**Checking the existence of symbol properties**

One way to improve the code in case of missing properties, is to write a `get` replacement, which gives more information. Unfortunately `get` does not give an indication if a property does not exist:

```
CL-USER 54 > (get 'decor 'prior-prob-a)
NIL
```

Did the property not exist or was the value `nil`?  We don't know from using `get`.

We need to check whether a property is actually present. This can be done with the standard Common Lisp function `get-properties`.

```
(defun safer-get (symbol property)
  (multiple-value-bind (property0 value tail)
      (get-properties (symbol-plist symbol)
                      (list property))
    (declare (ignore property0))
    (assert tail ()
      "Property ~a not found for node ~a." property symbol)
    value))
```

Example:

The property `prior-prob` exists for a symbol `decor`:

```
CL-USER 49 > (safer-get 'decor 'prior-prob)
0.5
```

The property `prior-prob-a` does not exist for a symbol `decor`:

```
CL-USER 47 > (safer-get 'decor 'prior-prob-a)

Error: Property PRIOR-PROB-A not found for node DECOR.
  1 (continue) Retry assertion.
  2 (abort) Return to level 0.
  3 Return to top loop level 0.
```

Thus you get the information which property it is and for which symbol. So the error message comes earlier (not when later one uses `NIL`) and has more information.